# Firebase: Invisible reCaptcha does not work in React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication, invisible-recaptcha

## Overview

Hi, I am using **Firebase's invisible reCaptcha** for phone number authentication in my **React JS** application. As per the **documentation** of Firebase you need to provide **id** (e.g. `sign-in-button`) of the button which handles submit of login form.

## Expected Behaviour

Once user click on **that button**, Firebase's invisible reCaptcha should kick in and checks if it has been **resolved** by the user or not. If reCaptcha is **resolved**, a `callback`  provided by `new firebase.auth.RecaptchaVerifier('...', {})` will be fired. In that callback we are supposed to **send an OTP** code to user's phone number.

## Issue

What's the happening is that the `callback` is not being fired unless the **OTP isn’t sent** on submit of the login form which **doesn’t make sense** because sending OTP needs to **handled by the callback** provided by invisible reCaptcha and not by **sending the OTP with onSubmit** of the form.

## Version

**"firebase": "^7.15.1",**

## Code

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/auth';

firebase.initializeApp({
  apiKey: 'xxx',
  authDomain: 'xxx',
  databaseURL: 'xxx',
  projectId: 'xxx',
  storageBucket: 'xxx',
  messagingSenderId: 'xxx',
  appId: 'xxx',
  measurementId: 'xxx',
});

class App extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    window.reCaptchaVerifier = new firebase.auth.RecaptchaVerifier('login-button', {
      size: 'invisible',
      callback: () => {
        // callback is not being fired automatically
        // but after the OTP has been sent to user's
        // phone number which makes this callback useless
        // as opposed to Firebase's documentation
      },
    });
  }

  handleSubmit = event => {
    event.preventDefault();

    firebase
      .auth()
      .signInWithPhoneNumber('+1 XXX-XXX-XXXX', window.reCaptchaVerifier)
      .then(confirmationResult => {
        window.confirmationResult = confirmationResult;
      })
      .catch(() => {});
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <input />
        <button id="login-button">Submit</button>
      </form>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Has anyone solved this yet @Vinay @Doug?  I'm having the same issue.

Comment: Hi @ChrisEaheart it still hasn’t been solved. I had raised a **GitHub Issue** and will suggest to keep looking for any updates over there: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/3314

Comment: you can it here: [nextjs with firebase phone auth](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75156416/7956318)

Answer (score 5):

This is what I'm using, seems to work well

```
const [token, setToken] = useState("");

useEffect(() => {
  new firebase.auth.RecaptchaVerifier("request-otp", { size: "invisible" })
    .verify()
    .then(setToken);
}, []);
```

Comment: The `.verify()` callback is what I was looking for. I was using the `.render()` function instead but verify was what I needed, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Usually, reCAPTCHA needs to be rendered **before** it is used. So, for example, the following code works. The only modifications from the code in the question are:

- reCAPTCHA is rendered explicitly in `componentDidMount`
- form's `onSumbit` is not used therefore (it actually never fires in this scenario, because reCAPTCHA callback processes the submit event instead)

Working solution with pre-render:

```
class App extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    const reCaptchaVerifier = new firebase.auth.RecaptchaVerifier('sign-in-button', {
      size: 'invisible',
      callback: function (response) {
        console.log('It works!');
      },
    });
    reCaptchaVerifier.render();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form>
        <input />
        <button id="sign-in-button">Submit</button>
      </form>
    );
  }

}
```

Comment: I don't think this pre-render is a nice solution for this as I can get this code working in Vanilla JS without it. For your reference you can check here: https://github.com/vinaysharma14/react-firebase/blob/master/src/App.tsx